# How to get available bitrates and quality level information for DASH assets in CAF Receiver?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, caf-receiver-sdk

I am developing a CAF Receiver that casts DASH assets. Now I want to know what available bitrates exist for an asset, and for each segment get the quality level.

I have previously developed a V2 Receiver. In V2, it was easy to get the information with the Media Player Library (MPL). I used StreamInfo.bitrates to get the available bitrates and StreamingProtocol.getQualityLevel() to get the quality level. But I can not find anything similar in CAF. How can I get that information using the CAF Receiver?

Comment: You can file a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Answer (score 0):

try use this event to know the full information you need

```
 playerManager.addEventListener(cast.framework.events.EventType.BITRATE_CHANGED, (event) => {
            log('[mediacast:events:BITRATE_CHANGED - ' + event.totalBitrate);
            stats.bitrate = event.totalBitrate;
            console.log(playerManager.getStats());
});
```